# Data not inserted in database using laravel 8

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to save data from a form modal to database .

So , I'm using the following code :

Controller :

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{

   if ($files = $request->file('casting_photo'))

    {
  
       $destinationPath = public_path('public/castingimages'); // upload path         
       $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
      
            $cast = new Casting;

            $cast -> casting_name= $request->input('casting_name');
            $cast -> casting_cin= $request->input('casting_cin');
            $cast -> casting_email= $request->input('casting_email');
            $cast -> casting_phone= $request->input('casting_phone');  
            $cast -> casting_gender= $request->input('casting_gender');
            $cast -> casting_address= $request->input('casting_address');
            $cast -> casting_city= $request->input('casting_city');
            $cast-> casting_photo=$profileImage;

              $cast->save();

    }
    
}
```

View :

```
   <x-app-layout>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col app-col">
          <div class="mb-2">
            <h1>Castings</h1>

            <div class="top-right-button-container">
              <button type="button" data-target="#castingmodel" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg top-right-button  mr-1">Add New
</button>
              <div class="col-xl-6">
                <div id="result"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <div class="separator mb-5"></div>
          </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>



 <div class="modal fade" id="castingmodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalContentLabel">New message</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
    <form method="post"  class="needs-validation tooltip-label-right" id="formcast" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id" />

                <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="casting_name" id="casting_name" >
                  <div class="invalid-tooltip">Name is required!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                  <label>CIN</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="casting_cin" id="casting_cin" required>
                  <div class="invalid-tooltip">CIN is required!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                  <label>EMAIL</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_email" required>
                  <div class="invalid-tooltip">EMAIL is required!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                  <label>PHONE</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_phone" required>
                  <div class="invalid-tooltip">PHONE is required!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative">
                  <label>Radio</label>
                  <div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input type="radio" id="jQueryCustomRadio1" name="casting_gender"  class="custom-control-input" required value="homme">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="jQueryCustomRadio1">Homme</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input type="radio" id="jQueryCustomRadio2" name="casting_gender" class="custom-control-input" required value="femme">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="jQueryCustomRadio2" >Femme</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                  <label>ADDRESS</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_address" required>
                  <div class="invalid-tooltip">ADDRESS is required!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                  <label>CITY</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="2" name="casting_city" required>
                  <div class="invalid-tooltip">CITY is required!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" name="casting_photo" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="createBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

                <div class="result"></div>
           
            </div>

               </form>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>




 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#formcast').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"castings",
                data : $('#formcast').serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                    $('#castingmodel').modal('hide')
                    alert("Data saved");
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                    alert("Data not saved");
                }
            });
        });
     });
 
</script>
</x-app-layout>
```

It doesn't show any error and the data is not inserted into the database.

I checked the file `.env` the parameters of the database are correct.

I don't know if it is because of the input file that I'm uploading in the form

Comment: does it get to your function?

Comment: check that with returning something in function and console it in your response

Comment: also return your request in function and make sure it has your photo

Comment: I checked, it returns the response in function

Comment: and it has your photo?
i think you are not sending your photo through you ajax request and so base on your code in your function, your data will not be saved

Comment: I think this is the problem, so how can I send the photo via ajax request?

Comment: read this link : https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-6-ajax-image-upload-with-preview-using-base-64

there are many examples in google
if you know vuejs i will put some code for you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of serialize ,you can use form data to submit your form like below

```
$('#formcast').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
   var formData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{ url('/agents') }}',
                data: formData,
                success: function(response){
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function(error){
                   
                }
            });

        });
```

Since in your backend you are creating record only if you have image uploaded .so make sure to upload file as well

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line:

```
 $cast = new Casting;
```

Shouldn't it be

```
 $cast = new Casting();
```

with brackets?
Also you are trying to get data from form

```
($cast -> casting_name= $request->input('casting_name'); )
```

while the content type of your jQuery ajax request is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded
So 2 options:
1- get data from controller like this:

```
 $cast -> casting_name= $request->get('casting_name');
```

(with the 'get' instead of 'input'

2- Keep the controller and update the ajax content type